# Android SDK is not installed but it shows installed

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

i am beginner in android programming and i am facing problem in installation.

[image]

When i select the proper location. It shows Android SDK is up to date but it does not accept the path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check files under sdk, it should looks like this.
[image]

Comment: No it does not look like this. How should i download this?

Comment: Try reinstall android studio with dmg.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and it turned out the problem was with my proxy settings - try updating these under System Settings>HTTP Proxy, then try again